# cut a div and html inside it and paste it into a different div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a 3rd party script in which i have no control over the html and can only modify basic css . I just wanted to know if its possible to cut a div and all the html inside it and paste it in a different div as soon as the page loads?

suppose we have

```
  <div id="example-one">
      <ul class="nav">
         <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Billing Address</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="list-wrap">
          hello
      </div>
  </div>
```

and when the page loads jquery cuts the whole html specifying the div id `"example-one"` and paste it into a new div name it be `"new-div"`. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to find the answer to my question. I tried one jQuery function and it worked like a charm as I wanted. I am pasting the code so that it can be useful to anyone who has the exact problem as mine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1').insertAfter('.div2');
});
```

This will cut the `div1` HTML and move it to `div2`.

Answer (score 34):

There is no cut & paste in DOM, you can append it(*move it*) to a different point in DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example-one').appendTo('#new-div');
});
```

In case that you want to create a `div#new-div` element and it doesn't exist:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('<div/>', { id: 'new-div' }).appendTo('#somewhere').append($('#example-one'));
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering me again to one of my question . actually its a 3rd party script foxycart. i cant keep both the divs. as its carrying information for checkout of a item so duplicate of values in hidden fields would cause failure in checkout . is there no way we can cut and paste that ?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can use something like this:

```
$("#example-one").append("<div id="new-div"></div>"); // Add #new-div to the DOM
$("#new-div").html($("#list-wrap").html()); // Giv #new-div the content of #list-wrap
$("#list-wrap").remove(); // Destroy #list-wrap
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        <div id="example-one">
              <ul class="nav">
                 <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Billing Address</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="list-wrap">
                  hello
              </div>
          </div>


        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#example-one').appendTo('.new-div');
        });

**out put:**
    <div class='new-div'>
     <div id="example-one">
              <ul class="nav">
                 <li class="nav-one"><a href="#featured" class="current">Billing Address</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="new-div">
                  hello
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

OR you can use below Code
 $('#example-one').clone().appendTo('.new-div');

Answer (score 2):

Although it is tagged jQuery, people might want a vanilla alternative
Try out on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/VanKusanagi/go06kcre/

In essence the core code is:

```
function moveDiv(){
  var exampleDiv = document.getElementById("example-one");
  var newDiv = document.getElementById("new-div");
  newDiv.appendChild(exampleDiv);
}
```

You can load it on DOMCONTENTLOADED (fires earlier than window's load event)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    moveDiv();
});
```

Or Window's load event

```
window.onload = moveDiv;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the element you want to get the contents then [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) to new container

```
$("#example-one").children().appendTo("#new-div");
```

Or if you mean to move the div with the ID you can use

```
$("#example-one").appendTo("#new-div");
```

Both methods will move the elements

To run a script when the page loads you can use [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function() {
    // code here will run after DOM loads
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like:

```
$("#new-div").html($("#example-one"));
$("#example-one").hide;
```

This will basically take all html from #exmaple-one and put it into #new-div and hide the #example-one div.

Here is a jFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/sf35D/

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
var text=jQuery('#div2');
jQuery('#div2').remove();
jQuery('#div1').append(text);
```

Comment: This does not really give anything compared to the other answers. Especially as the question has no `div1` or `div2`

Comment: This is not a spoon feeding work and It's just an example to show you how to work accordingly, the further work will be done by yourself and this script is already tested.

Comment: This is better because others are not removing the original div which OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to wrap those contents in parent divs, and then simply "copy\paste" the html content of it ?

Example

```
<div id="content_1">
 <div class="nav">
  <span>very nice website...</span>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="content_2"></div>
```

Then, in jquery (since the question asks about jquery, but it could be done un pure js) :

```
var mash_potatoe = $("#content_1").html(); // Copy content
$("#content_1").html(''); // Erase content
$("#content_2").html(mash_potatoe); // Paste content
```

The result would be :

```
<div id="content_1"></div>
<div id="content_2">
<div class="nav">
  <span>very nice website...</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#div1').append($('#div2'));
```

This code cut the **div2** from its current place and paste it inside of **div1**